# Hibernate envers: RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED vs @NotAudited

Tags: java, hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

I try to audit an entity but I don't want to audit its relationships. If I put @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED) in @ManyToOne relations, this works and I don't have any exception, but when I try to use the same annotation in a @onetomany with the param mappedby defined, I have an exception that says me that I have to audit the other entity.

Example:

```
@Table(name = "OWNERS")
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Audited
public class Owner {
...
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  private User user;
...
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner" )
  private Set<Pet> pets = new HashSet<Pet>();
...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

When you use @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED) you are telling hibernate not to audit this entity but audit the relation so you hibernate will save the id of the referenced entity. Thats why Pet must be an @Audited entity.

If you do not want to store the relation at all you need to use @NotAudited

Check this [Whats the difference between @NotAudited and RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED in Hibernate EnVers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661682/whats-the-difference-between-notaudited-and-relationtargetauditmode-not-audited)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have two options here:

1. Actually audit the entity `Pet`, if applicable;
2. Use the annotation `@NotAudited` instead of `@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)`. Think about it, The audit table for `Owner` doesn't have to persist the `Pet`'s associated. If it does, use option 1.

Hope it helps!